# Difference between Psionic and Psychic abilites

Tags: marvel

What is the fundamental  difference between psionic and psychic powers? How can a power be classified as a psionic or psychic power?

Comment: I don't know about Marvel in particular, but more generally the word 'psychic' generally covers any kind of mental power, including or especially those that are magical in original, whereas 'psionic' is usually restricted to science-fiction mental powers, i.e., that do not use magic.

Comment: That was my understanding too based on wikipedia. But i have seen these two terms used interchangably. Also, Charles Xavier says he is psychic in the first movie but his power comes from genetic mutation and not magic.

Comment: Yep.  Psychic is generic enough to describe both psionics and magic (though some people are fussier about this) but never, or only very rarely, the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the Marvel wiki entry, [psychic powers](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Psionic_Entity#Psi) are "any and all extrasensory and extraphysical powers stemming from the mind, specifically astral projection, clairvoyance, empathy, levitation, precognition, psychokinesis/telekinesis, telepathy, and teleportation." Basically, they're mind powers.

[Psionic energy](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Psionic_Entity#Psion) is a specific sort of energy that can be used to boost psychic powers.

> Psions or Psionic Energy is the type of energy used by telepaths, or to mechanical means to stimulate the natural psionic powers. All the living beings produce Psions and only a few can detect this energy. The Mutant; Charles Xavier created Cerebro to enhance his already powerful telepathic abilities. The machine allowed him to monitor the entire planet and detect the specific mutant psionic signatures. Being such as the Phoenix Force and Shadow King are Psionic Entity's being made out of Psions. Psionic beings or telepaths Astral Projecting in their Astral Form can enter the Astral Plane, a dimension made of Psions.

So, in short, unless you count being able to access psionic energy as a power in and of itself, there are only psychic powers, some of which are boosted by the use of psionic energy, and creatures who are composed of said psionic energy, some of which have psychic powers.

Obligatory caveat, my source is a wiki editable by anyone, and writers have likely used the terms interchangeably.

Comment: So when a character possess psionic powers he actually has psychic powers and vice versa?

Comment: There are apparently people with psychic powers who don't employ psionic energy. I have not yet found an example of a "psionic entity" composed of psionic energy that doesn't have psychic powers as well, but I feel like it ought to be possible.

Comment: So all psionic powers are psychic powers but not necessarly vice versa?

Comment: Yes. All psionic powers are psychic powers which are using psionic energy to boost them.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will up vote and accept it tomorrow from my pc as i  am on a nokia x2 now.

Comment: @Analyst1996: ?